# Need to know the way to work with Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel. I have read several documentation of it and went through the examples (only of XML DSL) that Apache provide with its jar. I have a spring MVC project running over tomcat, and in the same project I need to include an Integration Framework. I have installed JBoss plugin for tooling so that I can drag and drop components but palette isn't showing any component but a message *'A palette is not working'*. So, please suggest me how should I proceed to implement the same. For now I am referring ***Camel in Action***. And, if possible, then provide an example to send a https request to any URL with some header parameters and transform its response and print it on console or write it to any file or give another https request to any other URL with the payload.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is much too broad. And: stack overflow is really really **not** a coding service. You start things by writing your **own** code that you show here to get help on it. Instead of dropping ideas/requirements and hoping that other people do all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Why you added the Talend tag ?

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned that you installed the JBoss plugin for tooling, do you mean that you installed the JBoss Fuse Tooling?

Which version of Eclipse or JBoss Developer Studio are you using? Which OS are you using?

In Fuse Tooling, several examples are provided based on archetypes, I let you check the "CHAPTER 5. CREATING A NEW FUSE PROJECT" in
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2.1/pdf/Tooling_User_Guide/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.2.1-Tooling_User_Guide-en-US.pdf